# Suppress IProgressIndicator in Resharper ContextAction

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-6.1, resharper-plugins

I'm writing a Resharper ContextAction, and the progress indicator that pops up after a second keeps stealing the focus from my text box. How can I suppress the progress indicator that gets passed to ExecutePsiTransaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ups. Try overriding ExecuteBeforeProgressAndTransaction and calling your dialog from there instead of from ExecutePsiTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Just pass NullProgressIndicator.INSTANCE

Comment: I tried overriding `BulbItemImpl.Execute`, passing a `NullProgressIndicator.INSTANCE` to `ExecutePsiTransaction`, but the same problem persists. It must be triggered some other way, but I can't find where.

Answer (score 0):

You better to get necessary data before starting transaction.